# deny update on a subset of documents in a mongo collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection hook on one collection to spawn an "empty calendar". This is more or less a base that needs to be maintained unchanged, that is to say, deny updates.

```
Players.after.insert({
  // creates an empty calendar
  Calendars.insert({
    playerId: this._id
  });
});
```

On most calendars, update would be perfectly okay, but on these specific calendars which are inserted via this hook, I want to deny updates.

```
Calendars.deny({
  update: function (userId, doc) {
    // don't allow "blank" calendar to be updated
  }
});
```

What is the secure way to manage denying updates of a subset of documents in a collection with meteor?

Comment: Can you use 'defineProperty' and make 'writable' to 'false'?

Comment: Probably easiest to set a flag on the otherwise empty Calendars. For example `preventUpdate: true`. Then inside the update deny function: `return doc.preventUpdate === true`

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment, seeing as nobody has answered. One way to do this is to set a flag on the 'empty' records. For instance:

```
Players.after.insert({
  // creates an empty calendar
  Calendars.insert({
    playerId: this._id
    preventUpdate: true
  });
});
```

Your deny function can then be something like:

```
Calendars.deny({
  update: function (userId, doc) {
    return doc.preventUpdate === true
  }
});
```

This should be secure because the `doc` parameter in the deny function is the unmodified document from the database so couldn't be tampered with from the client.